# Quantum systems - Dissipation and normalisation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, dissipation, unitarity

If we have a quantum system described by the time-dependent Schrödinger equation:

\begin{equation}
i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(x, t)=\left[-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2 m} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}+V(x, t)\right] \Psi(x, t)
\end{equation}

A dissipative system is a system whose hamiltonian is not Hermitian (that is, doesn't preserve the norm):

\begin{equation}
\int\psi^{*}(H\psi) = \int (H\psi^{*}\psi)
\end{equation}

1. What does "dissipative" mean in this context?
2. Why a "dissipative system" doesn't conserve the norm?
3. Any complex (or imaginary) potential is dissipative?
4. An example of potential that leads to a dissipative system?